# creating website in notepad. have trouble

Tags: html, css, notepad

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>

        <style type="type/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            background-attachment:fixed;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:49px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-family:Papyrus, Times New Roman;
        }
        h3 {
            font-family:Times New Roman:
        }
        </style>
    </head>
```

this is how I have the head written. my website isn't doing any style. is there anything wrong with this code. when I put this in a brower and look at the source it doesn't show the body,h1,h2,h3 and tags its just looks like plain text. how can I fix this.

Comment: check the browser's web console (e.g. shift-ctrl-k in firefox). it'll show any errors caused by your code (e.g. bad css directives)

Comment: I don't see any `body`, `h1`, etc tags in your source.

Comment: On a side note, you dont need the `type="type/css"`

Answer (score 1):

The style type should be "text/css" not "type/css", though you really don't need it.

```
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                background-attachment:fixed;
            }
            h1 {
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size:49px;
            }
            h2 {
                font-family:Papyrus, Times New Roman;
            }
            h3 {
                font-family:Times New Roman:
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
font-family:Times New Roman:
```

Should be

```
    font-family:Times New Roman;
```

On a side note... Look at notepad++

; not :